# What is the scriptural basis for believing the judgement comes immediately at death?

Tags: bible, soteriology

In my discussions I've talked to Christians who had different concepts about the specifics of salvation which seem to make a significant difference, at least if one's only unrepented sin is not believing.  Most Christians have said to me that we're all judged at the exact moment of death, but some have told me that after death we're confronted by God/Jesus and then judged.  I don't know if this is a denominational difference or not.  It seems significant that in the second instance belief would no longer be a problem when faced directly.  It's because of this that I've been told non-Christians are not necessarily in any more hot water than Christians .

My question is, what is the scriptural basis for the belief that we're judged at the exact moment of death?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This question is not really appropriate for this particular site, as it would spark quite a bit of debate.  What would be better is, "What is the basis for the belief that we are judged immediately after death?"  and then one for the idea that we are first confronted by God/Jesus.  The key is to have a question where there is one true objective answer that is not subject to debate.

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping to frame the question as pliable with an objective answer by making it about what the bible has to say.

Comment: There are numerous interpretations of scriptures to determine the order of salvation. I don't feel like straight interpretation is sufficient here.

Comment: Answer: Whichever one God tells us when we meet him face to face.  Until then, our best tack is to read the scriptures plainly, humbly, and with the understanding that "now we *only* know in part."

Comment: Edited per narnian's recommendation.

Comment: From Hebrews - "It is appointed unto a man once to die, and then the judgement." Hebrews 9:27

Comment: Revelation 20 makes it pretty clear that judgment happens after the Millenium in terms of chronology.  The only debatable part is whether or not we are conscious in-between.

Comment: According to John 3:18 (He who believes in Him is not condemned; but he who does not believe is condemned already, because he has not believed in the name of the only begotten Son of God") indicates that judgment has been determined while we are still alive. So you are probably wondering if the judgment is CARRIED OUT quickly after death or not.

Comment: I don't get why this question should be closed. He's asking for what the Bible says about a certain subject. Isn't that pretty much what this site is about?

Comment: If the question was just whether one believed in the existence of God, then presumably if one met God and then was judged, everyone would be saved. But logically this can't be what the Bible means or there wouldn't be all the warnings about unbelief and the dangers of Hell. In any case the Bible specifically answers that point. James 2:19 (NIV) "You believe that there is one God. Good! Even the demons believe that—and shudder."